# Keyboard-shortcut for Firefox print preview?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, firefox, printing

For testing the print output during web development, I find myself frequently pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> followed by <kbd>V</kbd>. That is, open "File" menu, then execute "Print preview".

This is cumbersome.

Is there a single keyboard-shortcut for that?

Or, is it possible to create a custom keyboard-shortcut for "Print preview" in Firefox?

In some browsers, this was possible via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, but nowadays this triggers private browsing instead.

Is there some lesser-known undocumented keyboard-shortcut for that? Or, does provide Firefox any means to configure this shortcut on my own?

Comment: There's no direct shortcut to print preview native to Firefox (if you display the menus, the shortcuts are shown in the menu if there is one).  You could create your own shortcut, or figure out a workaround, like in your answer.

Comment: @fixer1234 I improved my question to make clear that creating a custom keyboard-shortcut would also be in scope. So feel free to provide an answer explaining how to create a custom keyboard-shortcut, if you know how to do that in Firefox. (I have no idea and didn't find any hints in the MDN.)

Comment: Use any provision for binding key combinations.  You've got the key sequence (Alt+F,V or F10, V).  There are a bunch of add-ons to create a shortcut (e.g., https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/shortkeys/, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimium-ff/, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/saka-key/).  I've never used one, so can't recommend.  There are also things like AutoHotKey.

Answer (score 4):

I found a slightly shorter sequence: <kbd>F10</kbd> followed by <kbd>V</kbd>. This works because "File" is the first menu.

However, this is still cumbersome and I'd love get to know about a real keyboard-shortcut.

Comment: Menu hotkeys do the job, but note that they're locale-specific. E.g. in Polish you'd need to type <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd>, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, then <kbd>G</kbd>.